# Finding points in the same quadrant, when do I use polar coordinates?

Tags: geometry

1. Which two points of the following are in the same quadrant:

$$(1,4),(e,-1),(2,\frac{\pi}{2}),(-3,-5),(-6.4,\frac{1}{3})$$

I am confused about this question, because it doesn't say anything about polar coordinates.

If $(2,\frac{\pi}{2}$) a polar coordinate, then it is in no quadrant.  (I.e., between 1 and 2) but if we take the literal value of $\frac{\pi}{2}1.57$ then it is in the first quadrant.

Also, what am I supposed to do for $e$? What value is this?  Is it equal to Eulers number?

Comment: I think these points are in cartesian coordinates; if this is the case, then the five points are in quadrants 1,4,1,3,2.

Comment: The problem should specify whether those are polar or Cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to look at the angle formed between the point and the $x$-axis. If you have $P = (r, \theta)$ in polar coordinates, then:

- $P$ is in the first quadrant $\iff 0 \leq \theta < \pi/2$;
- $P$ is in the second quadrant $\iff \pi/2 \leq \theta < \pi$;
- $P$ is in the third quadrant $\iff \pi \leq \theta < 3\pi/2$;
- $P$ is in the fourth quadrant $\iff 3\pi/2 \leq \theta < 2\pi$;

If $P = (x,y)$ in rectangular coordinates, then:

- $P$ is in the first quadrant $\iff$ $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$;
- $P$ is in the second quadrant $\iff$ $x < 0$ and $y \geq 0$;
- $P$ is in the third quadrant $\iff$ $x \geq 0$ and $y < 0$;
- $P$ is in the fourth quadrant $\iff$ $x < 0$ and $y < 0$;

You can assume that $e$ is Euler's constant.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to look at the signs of those numbers. You know that $(x,y)$ is

- in the first quadrant, if $x > 0$ and $y > 0$;
- in the second quadrant, if $x < 0$ and $y > 0$;
- in the third quadrant, if $x < 0$ and $y < 0$;
- in the fourth quadrant, if $x > 0$ and $y < 0$.

So, for example, (1,4) is in the first quadrant because both $1$ and $4$ are positive integers. And $(e, -1)$ is in the fourth one because $e$ is approximately $2.7$ and it's positive, while $-1$ is negative. This is the way to find the right answer.